# Passing a variable to a second window using MVVMLight?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am building an application to teach myself MVVM and with some Googling (and some trial an error) I have managed to get to the point where I can open a second window from the ViewModel but not to pass a variable from one page to the other. This is my ViewModel.

```
    public VendorSelectViewModel()
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply pingresult = ping.Send("192.168.1.10");
        if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Success")
        {
            LoadVendorsAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            LoadVendors();
        }

        NextCommand = new RelayCommand(NextWindow);
    }

    public ICommand NextCommand { get; private set; }

    void NextWindow()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(selectedVendor.VendorName); 
        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("NextWindow"));
    }
```

In my view I have this

```
    public VendorSelectWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new Biz.Invoicer.VendorSelectViewModel();
        DataContext = _vm;

        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
    }

    private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
    {
        if (msg.Notification == "NextWindow")
        {
            var invoicerWindow = new InvoicerWindow();
            invoicerWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

So I know (or I think I know) this may not be a "Best Practice" but I will come back to this and refactor as I get to know the MVVM patern and MVVM Light better. Currently I am trying to pass a variable from the ViewModel of the first page (VendorSelectViewModel) to the Second page (InvoicerWindow) but I haven't managed to the syntax correct.

What do I need to do to pass a variable from one page to the next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can pass an arbitrary object as the parameter of the `IMessenger.Send<TMessage>` method - the `TMessage` type parameter is not restricted. E.g.:

```
//ViewModel:
void NextWindow()
{
    //...
    int someValue = 10;
    Messenger.Default.Send(someValue);
}

//View:
public VendorSelectWindow()
{
    //...
    Messenger.Default.Register<int>(this, MessageReceived);
}

private void MessageReceived(int value)
{
    //...
}
```

If however you find the `NotificationMessage` class particularly useful in your case you could make use of the generic `NotificationMessage<T>` version, which exposes additional property `Content` of arbitrary type `T`:

```
//ViewModel:
void NextWindow()
{
    //...
    int someValue = 10;
    Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<int>(someValue, "Notification text"));
}

//View:
public VendorSelectWindow()
{
    //...
    Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<int>>(this, MessageReceived);
}

private void MessageReceived(NotificationMessage<int> message)
{
    var someValue = message.Content;
    //...
}
```

Or, if that does not suit you, you could create your own class deriving from `NotificationMessage` and exposing additional members and use that as the message object.

Comment: i prefer the option of creating my own classes because it's explicit in what just happened on the recieving (registering) side. one class per type of event. SelectedVendorChangedNotificationMsg, SelectedVendorDeletedNotificationMsg... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a `NotificationMessage` to the messenger, you could pass an instance of your own custom type which may carry as many values you want:

```
void NextWindow()
{
    Console.WriteLine(selectedVendor.VendorName); 
    Messenger.Default.Send(new YourPayload() {WindowName = "NextWindow", Parameter = "some value..:");
}
...

public VendorSelectWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _vm = new Biz.Invoicer.VendorSelectViewModel();
    DataContext = _vm;

    Messenger.Default.Register<YourPayload>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
}

private void NotificationMessageReceived(YourPayload msg)
{
    if (msg.WindowName == "NextWindow")
    {
        string param = msg.Parameter;
        var invoicerWindow = new InvoicerWindow();
        invoicerWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

`YourPayload` is a custom class with two properties, `WindowName` and `Parameter`.